# SwiftUI searchable on NavigationView always shown, hides only on scroll

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios15, xcode13

I'm writing a fairly simple SwiftUI app about movies and I have this issue where the new `.searchable` modifier on `NavigationView` is always being shown, whereas it should be hidden, unless you pull down on the `List`.

It hides it correctly if I scroll a bit up, and if I scroll down it also hides it correctly, but other than that, it's always being shown. See gif for clarification. (basically it should behave the same as in Messages app)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9t87V.jpg

My code for using the searchable is fairly simple:

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(/*** movie stuff ***/) { movie in
                    ///// row here
                }
            }
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            .onAppear {
                // load movies
            }
            .navigationTitle("Discover")
            .searchable(text: $moviesRepository.searchText, placement: .toolbar, prompt: "Search...")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"whereas it should be hidden, unless you pull down on the List"* - this is wrong assumption... probably you are confusing it with refresh control. It behaves as designed.

Comment: Then I got the wrong impression, I apologise - I'm still new to iOS dev. Is there a way to mimic such search functionality with SwiftUI or with UIKit?

Comment: Your code does exactly what you want and describe on my phone and simulator – search field is hidden until you move list down (Xcode 13.2, iOS 15.2) .. of course I tried with text only, so it might me the cells

Comment: @Asperi basically I want this functionality. https://imgur.com/nQVow5h

Comment: @ChrisR well what the heck, I honestly don't understand why isn't it working for me... Does it matter that the entire view is inside a tab view? (basically TabView is hosting 3 views, one of which is the one I posted) edit: nope, I pulled it out and put it as root view, still doesn't work :(

Comment: Yes, also works in TabView. But search field remembers, when you once made it visible – tab wise.

Comment: @ChrisR Yup, that's fine, it's just that it loads already visible, not sure if there is a way to hide it... but then again Asperi said it's working correctly, so I'm really not sure :/

Comment: how do you show your cells, are they really in a list?

Comment: @ChrisR Yes, the view is literally the same as I copied in my OP, except the rows themselves are a separate view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after adding a progress view above the list view, it suddenly started working the way I want it to. The code now is minimally changed and looks like this.

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            if /** we're doing search, I'm checking search text **/ {
                ProgressView()
                    .padding()
            }

            if !movies.isEmpty {
                List {
                    ForEach(/** movies list **/) { movie in
                        // movie row here
                    }
                }
                .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
                .navigationTitle("Discover")
                .searchable(text: $moviesRepository.searchText, placement: .toolbar,
                            prompt: Text("Search...")
                                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                )
            } else {
                ProgressView()
                    .navigationTitle("Discover")
            }
        }
    }
    .onAppear {
        // load movies
    }
}
```

And basically after adding the progress views, it started working the way I described it in my OP and the way it worked for ChrisR

Answer (score -2):

You can set the displayMode to ".automatic" and it will hidden by default.
[SearchFieldPlacement.NavigationBarDrawerDisplayMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/searchfieldplacement/navigationbardrawerdisplaymode)

```
List {
...
}
.searchable(text: $searchText, placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .automatic))
```